# Python Object Referencing Workaround

Tags: python-3.x, list

**Consider the code below:**

```
    outer_list = ['a', 'b', 0]
    inner_list = [1, 2, 3]
    
    final = []
    for item in inner_list:
        outer_list[-1] = item
        final.append(outer_list)
    
    print(final)
```

**with output :** [['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'b', 3]]

**My intended output is:**  [['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'b', 3]]

I understand this has to do with the fact that Python uses object referencing but i cant seem to find a way around this.

Anyone with a solution or alternative i'd appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List **concatenation** returns a **new** list object.

```
outer_list = ['a', 'b']
inner_list = [1, 2, 3]

print([outer_list + [item] for item in inner_list])
```

You could also achieve using [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp)

```
print(list(map(lambda item: outer_list + [item], inner_list )))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right.  Your assignment at line 6 modifies list outer_list and your append call add references to that list in final.  You can work on a copy of outer_list to get your result :

```py
    outer_list = ['a', 'b', 0]
    inner_list = [1, 2, 3]
    
    final = []
    for item in inner_list:
        l = outer_list.copy()
        l[-1] = item
        final.append(l)         
    
    print(final)
```